# Are static methods and class methods in Python only defined once per class?

Tags: python, oop

I want to know if there is a memory advantage when using this kind of method, decorated with `@staticmethod` and `@classmethod`. It could be useful when instantiating several objects of a class.

Comment: No method is defined more than once anyway, even without any decorator. **Write what you mean.** Only worry about memory optimisation if you have an indication that it's a problem.

Comment: I really don't know if method definitions has anything to do with memory foot-print!

Comment: instances of classes in Python do not carry around copies of the methods that exist in the class. Those function objects belong to the *class*. So, `vars(some_instance)` will show you instance attributes, but you'll see, the methods aren't there.

Comment: The duplicate title isn't a great match, but the answers there should be enlightening to you nonetheless.

Comment: Thanks all for the feedback and help. I already knew the purpose of static methods and class methods, I only wanted to know the memory treatment at a low level, but with your answers it is clear.